# asp.net datagrid on mouse over specific column cell display DIV with hyperlink derived from cell content

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET datagrid. I need to be able to display a DIV when on mouse over a specific column cell. The div has to contain a hyperlink, **with cell content concatenated at the end**.
I do not know how to approach this because my code is this:

```
    <div id="divResults" runat="server" style="width: 100%;">
                        <asp:DataGrid ID="grdResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" PageSize="4" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanged="grdResult_PageIndexChanging">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Emp Name" HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="25%"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="InternalPhone" HeaderText="extention" DataFormatString="{0:n4}" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DepName" HeaderText="department" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" HeaderStyle-Width="25%"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Telepone" HeaderText="phone" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Mobile" HeaderText="cellphone" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="E-Mail" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                                            <a href='mailto:<%# Eval("EmailAdd")%>'><img src="/_layouts/15/PortalAdditions/Images/mail_desk.png" border="0" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <img src="http://intranet/UserProfiles/pictures/<%# Eval("Employeeno")%>.JPG" class="phoneBookImage" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:DataGrid>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divResults -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the way to set the content of a div each time you mouse over the cell and display the div.

Your div :

```
<div id="content" style="visibility:hidden">
</div>
```

In the DataGrid :

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="text-align: center;" onmouseover="displayDiv(this.text());">
        <a href='mailto:<%# Eval("EmailAdd")%>'><img ... /></a>
     </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code JavaScript :

```
function displayDiv(textCell)
{
   $('#content').text(textCell) ;
   $('#content').css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You reply is much appreciated. I will check it out.